# Is there a way to get just the leak summary out of valgrind?

Tags: c++, bash, grep, valgrind

I am trying to make a script that will compile a .cpp file, run a leak check on the output, and then prompt the user whether to run the output or not automatically, and all of it works from that standpoint.

The problem is that I just want the

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
    definitely lost: ...
    possibly lost: ...
    still reachable: ...
    suppressed: ...
```

section of the output. I tried piping valgrind through grep, but it's not filtering properly. Any ideas?

Code (.sh)

```
clear; clear; clear; g++ *.cpp -o outputFile && echo "Compilation Successful!" && ( valgrind --leak-check=full ./output | grep  "LEAK\|lost:\|reachable\|suppressed\|possible" ) && {
echo "Do you want to run this file as compiled? (y/n)"
read decision
if [ "$decision" == "y" ]
then
./output
fi
echo "Script ended."
exit
}
echo "Something went wrong!"
exit
```

Output:

```
Compilation Successful!
{full valgrind output}
Something went wrong!
```

The something went wrong line seems to be caused by grep though since the rest of the script functions properly if the grep statement is removed.

Desired output:

```
Compilation Successful!
LEAK SUMMARY:
    definitely lost: ...
    possibly lost: ...
    still reachable: ...
    suppressed: ...
Do you want to run this file as compiled? (y/n)
>y
{program output displayed}
Script ended.
```

Comment: valgrind probably writes those diagnostics to its standard error, so you have to redirect standard error too, not just standard output.

Comment: You need `grep -E` to use the vertical bar.  I'm not sure why you are escaping it.  Also look into `grep -A4 LEAK`

Comment: Consider using 'make', it was designed to build sequences of build/test

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code with this:

```
clear; clear; clear; g++ *.cpp -o outputFile && echo "Compilation Successful!" && valgrind --leak-check=full ./outputFile &> CompileTempFile.txt && grep -A5 "LEAK SUMMARY:" CompileTempFile$
echo "Do you want to run this file as compiled? (y/n)"
read decision
if [ "$decision" == "y" ]
then
./output
fi
rm CompileTempFile.txt
echo "Script ended."
exit
}
rm CompileTempFile.txt
echo "Something went wrong!"
exit
```

EDIT: I updated the code, so I thought I'd share my current (smarter) version. :)

```
clear; clear; clear; g++ *.cpp -o outputFile && echo "Compilation Successful!" && echo "Running a leak test" && valgrind --leak-check=full ./outputFile &> CompileTempFile.txt && echo "Memory test completed!" && egrep -A5 "LEAK SUMMARY|no leaks are possible" CompileTempFile.txt && {
echo "Do you want to run this file as compiled? (y/n)"
read decision
if [ "$decision" == "y" ]
then
./outputFile
fi
rm CompileTempFile.txt
echo "Script ended."
exit
}
rm CompileTempFile.txt
echo "Something went wrong!"
exit
```